# how to make a button collector that increases the time left when you click

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```js
   let time = 10;
        const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({time:1000*time})
 collector.on("collect", async (btn) => {

let embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
                embed.setColor(0xff0000)
                embed.setAuthor({name:`${btn.user.username}`, iconURL:btn.user.displayAvatar({dynamic:true}))
                embed.setTitle(`You clicked`)
msg.edit{embeds:[embed]}
 time = 10;
})

        collector.on('end',(reason)=>{
            row.components.forEach(bt => {
                bt.setDisabled(true);
               });
      
                msg.edit({components:[row]})
        })
```

I tried this but I have no idea how to increase the time of the collector but it stops after 10 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something called as [`Collector#resetTimer`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collector?scrollTo=resetTimer) 
It basically resets the timer and you can easily use this while listening to collect event.

For example

```js
collector.on('collect', (i) => {
   if (i.customId !== 'reset') return;
   collector.resetTimer();
})
```

Do note that you can provide custom time as well using the [CollectorResetTimerOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorResetTimerOptions)